# KafkaStreams - how to handle corrupted data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have rather question what do to do in scenerio that KafkaStreams service is consuming some message and during processing it uncaught exception is thrown. At the moment I have implemented UncaughtExceptionHandler which is closing and cleanup old streams and starting new one, but it starts to consumes the same message which means that it ends with infinite loop of restarting...

In the end should I check the type of error and commit this message somehow to stop processing this error prone message?

Is it possible from this setUncaughtExceptionHandler method?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can better handle such messages as Poison pills and skip them using the following piece of code, and move forward.

public final class poisionPillEvent {

```
public static void ignoreEvents(String topic, String poisonedEventMessage, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
    final Pattern offsetPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*offset*\\w[ ]\\d+");
    final Pattern partitionPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w*" + topic + "*\\w[-]\\d+");
    
    try {
        // Parse the event to get the partition number and offset, in order to `seek` past the poison pill.
        Matcher mPart = partitionPattern.matcher(poisonedEventMessage);
        Matcher mOff = offsetPattern.matcher(poisonedEventMessage);

        mPart.find();
        Integer partition = Integer.parseInt(mPart.group().replace(topic + "-", ""));
        mOff.find();
        Long offset = Long.parseLong(mOff.group().replace("offset ", ""));
        consumer.seek(new TopicPartition(topic, partition), offset + 1);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to seek past bad message. {}", ex.toString());
    }
}
```

}